# Call to undefined method VirtueMartControllerInvoice::getInvoicePDF()

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i'm using **joomla 2.5.11 and virtuemart 2.0.26a**

getting a error in virtuemart when a order is changed to Confrimed Status..

```
Call to undefined method VirtueMartControllerInvoice::getInvoicePDF()
```

sometimes i'm getting

```
500: Internal Server Error
```

but when the order status is changed to Pending or something else..And mail to client is delivered without PDF.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers of VirtueMart? Unless you have messed around with the core code, it sounds like a bug. Also ensure you're running the latest version (**2.0.26d**, you're running **2.0.26a**)

Comment: Initially i got "Internal Server Error" . After reading a forum i have changed "controllers/invoice.php" . i have undone it. But still i'm getting same `500 error `.